# Cannot connect to wireless network with Ralink MT7601

Tags: wifi, kali-linux, raspberry-pi

I have been busy with my new Raspberry Pi B+ the whole day. I am trying to get on the wireless network. Here the steps I performed:

1. Check on kernel

   ```
   # uname -a
   Linux kali 3.12.26 #1 PREEMPT Thu AUg 21 20:47:35 EDT 2014 armv61 GNU/Linux
   ```
2. Check on device

   ```
   # lsusb
   Bus 001 Device 005: ID 148f:7601 Ralink Technology, Corp.
   Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver
   Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp.
   Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp.
   Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub[/code]
   ```
3. Check on module

   ```
   #lsmod
   ipv6                315768
   snd_soc_wm8804        7932
   snd_soc_pcm512x       9034
   mt7601Usta          601463
   ```
4. Check on ifconfig ra0

   ```
   Link encap:Ethernet  Hwaddr xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx
   inet6 addr:  fe80::aea2:13ff:fe12:4eb3/64 Scope:Link
   UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metrix:1
   RX packets:120992 errors:0 dropped:0 overrun:0 frame:0
   TX packets:720 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
   collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000
   RX bytes:27731290 (26.4MiB) TX bytes:74880 (73.1 KiB)[/code]
   ```
5. Check on network interface configuration file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces[/code]

   auto lo
   iface lo inet loopback

    auto eth0
   iface eth0 inet dhcp

   auto ra0
   iface ra0 inet dhcp
   wpa-conf /etc/wpa.config
   ```
6. Check on WPA configuration file

   ```
   sudo nano /etc/wpa.config
   network={
   ssid="Zy_private_9UYTXV2"
   proto=RSN
   key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
   pairwise=CCMP TKIP
   group=CCMP TKIP
   psk="12345678910"
   }
   ```
7. When I do an iwconfig check on ra0 I get the following results:

   ```
   Ralink STA ESSID:"11n-AP" Nickname:"MT7601STA"
   Mode:Auto Frequency=2.412 GHz Access Point: Not-Associated
   Bit Rate:1 Mb/s
   RTS thr:off Grafment thr:off
   Encryption key:off
   Link Quality=10/100 Signal level:0 dBm Noise level:0 dBm
   Rx invalid nwid:0 Rx invalid crypt:0 Rx invalid frag:0
   Tx excessive retries:0 Invalid misc:0 Missed beacon:0
   ```
8. When I try to change the ESSID from "11n-AP" to my network "Zy_private_9UYTXV2" then nothing changes if I run iwconfig ra0 again (same outcome as step 7)

   ```
   iwconfig ra0 essid Zy_private_9UYTXV2
   ```
9. When I try with the command iw dev, I get the following error:

   ```
   nl80211 not found
   ```

Please could anyone help me trying to fix this?